# Embed with @font-face only if the font is missing?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, font-family

I want to embed a font using @font-face, but only if this font is missing in user’s system. For example, if he has Verdana installed, then I want this rule to be applied in the browser:

```
font-family: Verdana;
```

But if Verdana is missing, I want it to be embedded through @font-face directive, like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Verdana;
  src: url(/some_path/verdana.ttf);
}
```

How to write the code for this selection?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Verdana;
  src: local('Verdana'), url(/some_path/verdana.ttf);
}
```